# Web server requests very slow from Android devices on local network

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, android

I have multiple pi's on my home network, all running web servers for various things, some hard-wired, some over wifi. Now these all work lighting fast from my desktop PC or laptop (both wifi and hardwired), as soon as you hit enter after typing the IP address the page appears.

Yet on my Android phone (connected via wifi), it takes forever for the page to appear, and often times out (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT). Watching the Apache logs it seems like the request doesn't even get through. One of my pi zero's (over wifi) is worse than a pi4 hardwired. But I've got a Pi Pico connected over wifi, and accessing a web server on that via Android is instant.

I have no idea what to look at next, I only have a single modem/router/wifi and I'm using the IP address in the browser, so I can't imagine why the pi's are so slow to get the request. It's only the pi/Android combination that is slow (tried on multiple Android devices). Any ideas?

Comment: yes, bad phone ...

Comment: @jsotola no it's the same on multiple Android devices, and those devices can access other web servers fine on the local network. It's the combination of Android/rpi that seems to cause the problem.

Comment: how do you know that it is an Android/rpi problem? ... you said nothing about web servers on any other devices